# How can I access my windows machine from my linux machine (physically next to each other) with low latency for gaming?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, remote-desktop

Currently, I'm dualbooting Ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10. I use ubuntu for work, which means I generally dont boot into windows until the weekend. This works ok, but I game on windows, and sometimes it would be nice to take a short gaming break during the week without having to deal with rebooting my system.

I have an unused machine which already has windows on it sitting next to me. Is there any way I can set this up so that I can just access my windows machine from my linux machine through a window (**with low latency**) such that when Im done gaming, I can just minimize the window and carry on with my work? I understand that the next best solution would be to have multiple inputs to my monitor and use a kvm switch, but I just wanted to check and see if there was a more convenient solution.

Answer (score 4):

Even I am a frequent user of remote desktop at my home network, I do not recommend to use it for gaming, since it's very expensive (in networking) to have a decent update rate. Bear in mind that if you use more colors in the image (16M colors), more time it'll take to transmit a single frame. In my personal experiences, I use no more than 256 colors to have a near-live desktop transmission; it may be ugly, but at least I can receive updates in real-time.

If you want to give it a try anyways, you can use [UltraVNC Server](http://www.uvnc.com/home.html) on Windows and use [Vinagre](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Vinagre) on Ubuntu to send and receive images respectively. And I'd give a try using a [crossover UTP cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#Pinouts_3) to achieve more speed between sender and receiver (e.g. not using a router/switcher, using a pure P2P network).

Answer (score 0):

One option that you might look into is running steam [Remote Play](https://store.steampowered.com/remoteplay). If you [add non-Steam games to your library](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2219-YDJV-5557) you can play them via remote play.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a look at either Steam Remote Play, or Moonlight. I tried Moonlight a few years ago, and it worked quite well.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a decent monitor, have your linux computer on one of your monitor inputs and your windows gaming computer on another input of that monitor.  Just push a button on the monitor and switch between linux and windows gaming.

Either manually move your usb keyboard and mouse between computers, or get a `USB Switch Selector` for $20 from amazon.

you will not want to game over vnc onto a windows machine, especially if the windows machine has an nvidia or amd graphics card.

> I have an unused machine which already has windows on it **sitting next to me**.

:facepalm: